# Why is the optimum vertex cover problem interesting?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-hard

Why is the optimum vertex cover problem interesting? Are there practical applications, or is it just another theoretical NP-hard problem?

Comment: This question already happens to have an answer on another SE site, found with a simple google search: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6670/vertex-cover-applications-in-the-real-world, but you'll probably want to jump straight to one of links therein: http://www.dharwadker.org/pirzada/applications/